# C# Enumerable.Except() only returns the same element once

Tags: c#, linq

When running the code below, I would expect to see the number 3, two times, but apparently the Except() method only returns the same element once.

```
List<int> x = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 3};
List<int> y = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };

var z = x.Except(y); /* returns 3, only once  */
```

In the documentation they say that the set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that do not appear in the second set. It is not documented that they return duplicate items only once.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Is this a bug, or do I miss something here?

The code of the Expect() method is available here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8.

Shouldn't they do "if (!set.Contains(element)) yield return element;" instead of "if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;"?

Comment: The definition of a `set` means that it doesn't contain duplicates, so this is working as intended.

Comment: The example contains "2.3" only once?

Comment: @xanatos - the page you linked seems to have only unique items in the first enumerable (`double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };`)

Comment: @Corak Aaaaah... The italian version (that is auto-translated https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) has the `2.3, 2.3` example... They then probably corrected it, but the page wasn't updated...

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this is not a bug; *set difference* here means that both sequences are treated as sets, consequently the result sequence contains each element only once. However, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) does not really enlarge on whether doubles can occur in the output or not.